# Объединение объектов в массиве по ключу

Tags: javascript, объекты, объединение, lodash

У меня имеется массив с разными данными , который выглядит примерно так:

```
[ {
   "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f10",
   "username": "ivan",
   "music": [
     "Metallica"
   ]
  },
  {
   "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f10",
   "username": "ivan",
   "interests": [
     "Music",
     "Djent"
   ]
  }, 
  {
   "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f13",
   "username": "alina",
   "interests": [
     "Music",
     "Literature"
   ]
  },
  {
   "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f13",
   "username": "alina",
   "music": [
     "Skyharbor"         
   ]
  }
]
```

Как с объединить объекты в массиве по ключам ('**_id**') следующим образом (приоритет lodash):

```
[ {
   "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f10",
   "username": "ivan",
   "music": [
     "Metallica"
   ],
   "interests": [
     "Music",
     "Djent"
   ]
  },
  {
   "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f13",
   "username": "alina",
   "music": [
     "Skyharbor"         
   ]
   "interests": [
     "Music",
     "Literature"
   ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сгруппировать по идентификаторам можно с помощью `groupBy`, а затем объединить пары с помощью `merge`:

```js
var users = [{
  "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f10",
  "username": "ivan",
  "music": [ "Metallica" ]
}, {
  "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f10",
  "username": "ivan",
  "interests": [ "Music", "Djent" ]
}, {
  "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f13",
  "username": "alina",
  "interests": [ "Music", "Literature" ]
}, {
  "_id": "556c978be20c7cd0087c6f13",
  "username": "alina",
  "music": [ "Skyharbor" ]
}];

console.log(
  _.map(
    _.groupBy(
      users,
      function (u) { return u._id }
    ),
    function (g) { return _.merge.apply(this, g) }
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

P. S. Прошу ногами не бить, в первый раз в жизни вижу lodash.